# Ignore duplicates when pushing nuget package to nuget.org from VSTS

Tags: c#, nuget, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I got a build in VSTS that are triggered on every commit in the repository. Everything works great with one exception.

We do not release a new version of the nuget package on every commit. So our nuget push build step fails with http status code 409. I've configured that step so that it can continue anyway.

Due to the error the build is just "partially successful". I'm using the a build badge which also states the same (without context).

How can I tell VSTS to ignore 409 or just replace the existing package (on nuget.org)?

Comment: Allow duplicates to be skipped is supported in NuGet Push Task now! (I updated my answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can’t ignore 409 error in VSTS build and can’t replace the existing package in server.

I recommend that you can push the package in the release and fail the release if package is existing.

Another way is that, you can check the package in server before push package (e.g. PowerShell, REST API) during the build and set the condition for push package task (Custom Condition).

For example:

1. Add a variable to build definition (e.g. hasPackage true)
2. Check packages (PowerShell, Rest API etc…)
3. If the package is existing, set the variable to false (["##vso[task.setvariable variable=hasPackage;]false"](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md))
4. Set Custom condition for push package task (e.g. eq(variables['hasPackage'],'false'))

Update:

Allow duplicates to be skipped is supported in NuGet Push Task now! (Just check **Allow duplicates to be skipped** option in NuGet Push task.

Comment: Any reason why It was removed from the dotnetcore push task? Thanks

Comment: "Allow duplicates to be skipped" option is not available for Nuget.org or any other external NuGet server.

Comment: We tried to use the "Allow duplicates to be skipped" option no TFS 2018. But it seems not to work. The log displays:  "T12:07:21.8171891Z ##[warning]The 'Allow duplicates to be skipped' option is currently only available on Visual Studio Team Services. If NuGet.exe encounters a conflict, the task will fail."

Any idea?

Comment: @Neo unfortunately not.

Comment: The _allowPackageConflicts_ can be specified in YAML snippet
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 6):

Use `-SkipDuplicate` flag (available since NuGet 5.1):

> (5.1+) If a package and version already exists, skip it and continue with the next package in the push, if any.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-push#options

Comment: Is there a way to use `-skipDuplicate` on a YAML file?

Comment: I am also looking for the same now to have skipDuplicate

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with duplicated packages on Azure Pipelines.

Solution proposed by starian chen-MSFT is cool but it requires some scripting.

We came to solution which requires less efforts. You can create command line step and invoke dotnet nuget push with the following parameters:

```
dotnet nuget push $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg --skip-duplicate --api-key $(Config.NuGetApiKey) --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

The key is parameter --skip-duplicate which just skips the packages if they already exist.

In variable $(Config.NuGetApiKey) define your API key for NuGet.org. You should make it secret variable, so that it does not appear anywhere in the logs.

Here is the YAML for this command:

```yaml
steps:
- script: |
   dotnet nuget push $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg --skip-duplicate --api-key $(Config.NuGetApiKey) --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
   
  failOnStderr: true
  displayName: 'Publish NuGet Package'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had zero luck with dotnet push - and here's my context:

My dotnet pack is set to include symbols and source
[image: inlucding source or symbols]

> and always generating a unique preRelease semVer.. (here's yaml version of above dotnet pack)

```yaml
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    nobuild: true
    includesymbols: true
    includesource: true
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: '$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyInformationalVersion.Major)'
    minorVersion: '$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyInformationalVersion.Minor)'
    patchVersion: '$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyInformationalVersion.Patch)'
```

... and yet I get 409 responses with my freshly generated semVer!!
** BLAH!! **

### My Solution: just use `NuGet Push` instead!

```yaml
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet push'
  inputs:
    command: push
    publishVstsFeed: 'b64b1c9a-18fc-4e6f-aae7-3726c813f034'
  continueOnError: true
```

[image: my preferred pipeline]

Now my `debug` build-configuration CI pipeline builds full-source-and-symbol-accompanied NuGet packages in pre-release mode without failing the pipeline or putting caution symbols on it. YAY

I use a separate near identical CI pipeline to build in 'release' mode and create 'release' style semVer's.

Edit:
In the Classic UI is a checkbox for Allow duplicates to be skipped.
[image]