# Response status code does not indicate success: 409 Conflict - The feed already contains

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am changing my Azure DevOps build to .NET Core.

It's all working except the final push step to get the package in my feed, I get this error:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 409 (Conflict - The
>   feed already contains 'mypackage 1.0.x' (Devops Activity ID: xxx))

In the old "Nuget Push" step there was an option to "Allow duplicates to be skipped", specifically to get around this problem - but this option is not available in the "dotnet push" step.

How can this be achieved in the dotnet core world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fine with "partially successful" status - just check "Continue on error" in Control options for the task.

If not - check here: [You have to check version of the package before pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46151147/3883976)

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished by dividing the process into Build and Release, because the the job in the release pipeline support skipping upload if a package with the same name and version already exists.

**Build pipeline**

Add a build with the following steps
[image]
Publish the compiled nupkg file as output of the build.

[image]

**Release pipeline**

Create a release pipeline connected to the build pipeline. Click Alow duplicated to be skipped.
[image]

Comment: That option is not available for external feeds, such as nuget.org

Comment: That seems to be correct that you cannot "allow duplicates to be skipped" when using an external feed.

Comment: That option to allow duplicates to be skipped is there on build as well as release pipelines; I don't see how doing the same thing in a release pipeline would change anything.

Comment: I just use the `NuGet push` task shown in this answer, in lieu of the `dotnet push` task - and I get the results I'm wanting (not using a release pipeline... everything is just in the CI pipeline) - [more details on my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74240063/1520850)